# Smoke sim appearing in solid view but not in Render - Cycles - Blender 3.5

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, smoke-simulation

I'm here again trying to make a quick smoke sim with a "steam" like appearance.
I followed a guide and this is the second time I use this sim. However, the first time I had to switch to Eevee to render out my animation, since Cycles wasn't rendering the smoke with a transparent background.

This time I have to use Cycles but the smoke just won't appear in either Lookdev or Render.

- I have set up the material for the domain object: I tried with standard Principled Volume and with Emission Volume.
- I have checked if the domain or the flow object are enabled in rendering.
- I baked the data with Modular type.
- I'm rendering a correct frame

If you need anything else I'll provide. Thanks!

[image: Domain Shading nodes]